# How to get the actual query that ctx.Database.SqlQuery<SomeType> generates?

Tags: entity-framework

I am using `ctx.Database.SqlQuery<SomeType>` to execute a stored procedure with a complex set of parameters.

I said complex since there are a few parameters with type `System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured`. The parameter is by itself is a table of user defined table type.

I am aware that I can do something like this:

```
ctx.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

However, the logs do **not** properly reveal the parameters with the type System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured. I do need the actual chunk of TSQL that shows the parameters and SP execution, so I can copy/paste into SSMS and do the rest of diagnosis there.

My SQL Server login does **not** have access right to run **SQL Profiler** on the database.

In normal scenarios, I would use query.ToString() to get the generated SQL. However, not sure how to do the same with `ctx.Database.SqlQuery`.